# R - Divide numbers between rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Trying to learn R and am stuck on an simple example. I want to regress the division of the next number from the previous. I have a data frame with one column, here an sample of the data:

`Close <- c(234.45,236.33,232.25,231.5,230.35)`

`x <- data.frame(Close)`

What I would like to get:

`m <- c(NA,1.008018789,0.982778289,0.996727827,0.995032423)`

`y <- data.frame(Close,m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can divide by the `lag` of the column

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    mutate(m = Close/lag(Close))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
x$m <- with(x, c(NA, Close[-1]/Close[-length(Close)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` we can use `shift` to get the previous value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, y := Close/shift(Close)]
x

#    Close         y
#1: 234.45        NA
#2: 236.33 1.0080188
#3: 232.25 0.9827360
#4: 231.50 0.9967707
#5: 230.35 0.9950324
```